# SQL - Rank table by year and month

Tags: sql, ranking

I've the following table:

```
Year  Month
 2010  11
 2010  12
 2011  1
 2011  2
```

How can I create the follwing rank:

```
 Year  Month Rank
 2010  11     1
 2010  12     2
 2011  1      3
 2011  2      4
```

thanksSQL -

Comment: Which database are you using?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using some database (such as SQL server, Oracle, Postgres etc.) which supports window function, you can use `dense_rank` ( or `rank` or `row_number` based one your data and requirement):

```
select
    t.*,
    dense_rank() over (order by year, month) rnk
from your_table
```